# javascript into php dont fires until file_get_contents return data

Tags: php, javascript, file-get-contents

i have this script into a php file, a front page call this script by ajax where i get the data and then i edit them - here in this example i just show them by echo. 
When the front page calls this script i want to display a loading icon for the user but the icon is not displayed until the file_get_contents finish. Any idea?

```
    echo "<script>$('.loader_icon').show()</script>";
      $data=  file_get_contents($url);
      echo "<script>alert('data')</script>"; 
    echo "<script>$('.loader_icon').hide()</script>";
```

The same result if i change the file_get_content by ob_start or culr.

Comment: Could you post your javascript AJAX call?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because your page is only being sent to the browser when the PHP script execution completes. It finishes running your entire PHP script and then only returns to the browser.

Before you submit your ajax request, you should show your loading icon and then hide in when you get a response from the server.

Comment: thanks for your answer @mcryan, actually this is the way that i choose to follow before your recommendation but this is not preferable. Is there any way to use (file_get_contents or the other) asychronous?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what you are asking. Can you elaborate? If you post your ajax code I can show you where / how to structure your code so that you will see the loading icon before your script completes.

Comment: Ok, understand the way that you suggest and this is the way that i did it, i display the icon before post the serialized data of my form, but i would like to do it from the php script. Anyway this is the ajax $.ajax({
  type: 'post',
  url: url,
  data: $('#myform').serialize()
 });

Comment: You can't do it from the PHP file and get the expected results, for the reasons I explained above. The entire PHP script will complete execution and then return the result to the browser and therefor only show the loading icon when `file_get_contents()` has completed. Just call `$('.loader_icon').show()` before you execute `$.ajax()`

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation and your help, the way i did it is your way